# ANTLR v4 multi-assignment

Tags: whitespace, variable-assignment, antlr4

In Terence Parr'S Definitiv ANTLR Reference on page 39 an assignment ist defined like this:

```
stat: expr (NL|SEMI)            # printExpr
| var EQL expr (NL|SEMI)        # assign        // x = 5; y = x     
| (NL|SEMI)                     # blank
;
...
WS  : [ \r\t]+ -> skip;
NL  : '\r' ? '\n';
SEMI: ';';
...
```

This works fine.

But, how can I achieve something like this **x = 6 y=x** ?

Here: two assignments **separated by a single whitespace** (WS is skipped, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language designed to be dependent on occasional whitespace significance is nearly always a bad idea, and moreso when trying to parse it using a context-free parser. That said, there are two alternatives, at least for this example:

First, put the `WS` on the hidden channel.  Then, use a predicate to test for a `WS` token in the token stream where it is significant:

```
| var EQL expr ( {atWS()}? | NL | SEMI )   # assign
```

Second, don't hide or skip the `WS`.  Then, use like any other token where it should be significant:

```
| var WS? EQL WS? expr ( WS | NL | SEMI )  # assign
```

And, add a rule to capture otherwise unused `WS`:

```
ws: WS ;  // will pollute the parse tree, but can be ignored there
```

Both alternatives have consequences, moderate to severe, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.